# What object should contain which? and is that right?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, solid-principles

I'm trying to integrate a **framework agnostic** composer package into Laravel. The package has  models as **plain vanilla php objects**, with no ORM.

I want to integrate these models with Laravel's Eloquent ORM. So I can use functionality such as `save()` and `find()` etc...

As multiple inheritance is impossible how could I add Eloquent's functionality to these models / objects?

Comment: I see no problem. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Because the models from the package i want to use are not Eloquent models.

Therefore I would have to create a third class that extends from one of these models and eloquent so it can inherit all of the goodness from both... but thats impossible.

Comment: I'm also a little confused on what exactly you are trying to do. Can you provided a clear example of what you want to happen?

Comment: Use dependency injection.

Comment: I just simplified the question, was not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Put your stuff in a trait, and include it in both:

```
trait ModelTrait {

    public function someAwesomeMethod()
    {
        return 'unicorns';
    }

}

class Model {

    use ModelTrait;

}

class EloquentModel extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {

    use ModelTrait;

}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, i think i did not make the question clear enough. I will close this question as I have re-written the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442294/how-to-inherit-eloquents-functionality-on-plain-php-objects THANK you! apologies.