# How to inherit Eloquent's functionality on plain PHP objects

Tags: php, inheritance, laravel, eloquent, solid-principles

**How can I have a plain php object from a third party package inherit all the goodness of Laravels Eloquent models?** see below:

---

The model class below is from a **third-party package**. It is **framework and ORM agnostic**, written in **plain PHP**. I cannot change it, only extend it. (example only)

```
class APlainPHPModelFromLibrary {

    protected $someAttribute;

    protected $someOtherAttribute;

    //...

    public function someFunction()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And here is my Laravel Eloquent version of this model class. I need to **extend Eloquent** from this class. Also I need to extend from the above VanillaPHPModel so it can inherit Eloquent's methods. I cant see a way around this.

```
class MyEloquentModelVersion extends Eloquent ... extends APlainPHPModelFromLibrary { // ??

    $guarded = [
        'EloquentGoodness',
        'EloquentGoodness'
    ];

    public function belongsTo()
    {
        //...Eloquent goodness
    }

    public function hasMany()
    {
        //,..Eloquent Goodness
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank god PHP offers multiple inheritance... No, really. You can't do that, unless that vanilla object can be changed, so it extends `Eloquent\Model`. Otherwise you could only use `trait` in order to c-p its features to another class that would extend Eloquent, but I doubt this would work for you.

Comment: So there is really no way around this... other then modifying the original repository?

Comment: What you could do is create a service provider that takes two arguments in its constructor, one is `APlainPHPModelFromLibrary` and one is a new instance of your `Eloquent` model. Then in the construct, you'd translate the properties of the `APlainPHPModelFromLibrary` object to the Eloquent model. This way you would utilize Laravel's beautiful IoC concept the way it should be done.

Comment: But then i would loose all the methods that `APlainPHPModelFromLibrary` has, no? can you give me an example maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes, you'd lose the methods. Maybe you could use all the methods you need and then perform the translation? Not sure exacly how you want to execute this, and I respect your choice that you aren't comfortable with telling us which exact third party library you're using.

Comment: Haha thank you, just a project that I do not want to let out of the box right now. I will look into this.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan Is the third party library yours you're saying?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66747/discussion-between-silkfire-and-andrewmclagan).

Answer (score 1):

This is just a suggestion. You'd probably be able to solve it in a multiple other ways.

**ThirdPartyServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php
    class ThirdPartyServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider {
        public function register() {
            $this->app->bind('ThirdPartyService', function($app, $third_party_model) {
                return new ThirdPartyService($third_party_model, new MyEloquentModelVersion());
            });
        }
    }
```

**ThirdPartyService.php**

```
<?php
    class ThirdPartyService {
       public $third_party_model         = null;
       public $my_eloquent_model_version = null;

       function __construct(APlainPHPModelFromLibrary $third_party_model, MyEloquentModelVersion $my_eloquent_model_version) {
          $this->third_party_model         = $third_party_model;
          $this->my_eloquent_model_version = $my_eloquent_model_version;
        }

        function translate() {
            // conversion code

            return $this;
        }
    }
```

In your controller:

```
$tpsp = App::make('ThirdPartyServiceProvider', $third_party_model);

$tpsp->translate()->my_eloquent_model_version;
```